# MicroPython (u)socket.accept()

Tags: python, html, sockets, esp8266, esp8266wifi

I have a Wemos D1 mini v3 and I'm making cheap interactable lights for in the classroom using this. I have been following a tutorial from randomnerds trying to solve the problem of creating an HTTP request to make the lights wireless.

Link: *https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-esp8266-micropython-web-server/*

The first part is all going fair and well! I can ping the ip being made from the boot.py:

```
try:
  import usocket as socket
except:
  import socket

from machine import Pin
import network

import esp
esp.osdebug(None)

import gc
gc.collect()

ssid = 'My SSID'
password = 'My Password'

station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

station.active(True)
station.connect(ssid, password)

while station.isconnected() == False:
  pass

print('Connection successful')
print(station.ifconfig())

led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
```

So yeah, this part works well. But it's the main.py I'm really struggling with. It's all going fine until I wanted to accept the connection of the socket. The program -kind of- holds itself while trying to accept the socket. Here is the code used in the tutorial:

```
def web_page():
  if led.value() == 1:
    gpio_state="ON"
  else:
    gpio_state="OFF"
  
  html = """<html><head> <title>ESP Web Server</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,"> <style>html{font-family: Helvetica; display:inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}
  h1{color: #0F3376; padding: 2vh;}p{font-size: 1.5rem;}.button{display: inline-block; background-color: #e7bd3b; border: none; 
  border-radius: 4px; color: white; padding: 16px 40px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}
  .button2{background-color: #4286f4;}</style></head><body> <h1>ESP Web Server</h1> 
  <p>GPIO state: <strong>""" + gpio_state + """</strong></p><p><a href="/?led=on"><button class="button">ON</button></a></p>
  <p><a href="/?led=off"><button class="button button2">OFF</button></a></p></body></html>"""
  return html

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 80))
s.listen(5)
print('Listening to socket')
while True:
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
  request = conn.recv(1024)
  request = str(request)
  print('Content = %s' % request)
  led_on = request.find('/?led=on')
  led_off = request.find('/?led=off')
  if led_on == 6:
    print('LED ON')
    led.value(1)
  if led_off == 6:
    print('LED OFF')
    led.value(0)
  response = web_page()
  conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
  conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
  conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
  conn.sendall(response)
  conn.close()
```

The program seems to at least print *'Listening to socket'*. But after that, nothing happens (even after half an hour). So, I'm asking you wonderful people, what am I doing wrong with this socket module?
Or are there any good alternatives using the wifi module with sending data?